# Converting from UNIX Timestamp to datetime results in OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, datetime, unix

I'm retreiving an endpoint from an API that comes back as: `Date(1516367982230)`
I named this `SentDate` in my script. The number between the brackets is a UNIX time stamp. I want to convert this to a normal date and time so I used a function I found on stackoverflow:

```
SentDate = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(SentDate[6:-2])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However I keep getting back this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What does `print(type(SentDate), SentDate)` output? Btw, 1516367982230 doesn't look like a valid *Ux* timestamp.

Comment: the print gives me: <class 'str'> /Date(1516375688523)/

It's a UX timestamp in miliseconds I believe

Comment: Python measures time in seconds so you'd need to divide by 1000 to convert from milliseconds first

Comment: This seems to do the trick, I've changed my code to:
SentDate = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(SentDate[6:-5])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Thanks for your help

Comment: post your fix as an answer below as an answer and after 24? hrs you can accept your own answer and gain valuable reputation points. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick, I've changed my code to:

```
SentDate = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(SentDate[6:-5])).strftime('%Y-‌​%m-%d %H:%M:%S') Thanks for your help
```

(Sumary: my timestamp was in miliseconds)